# data validation : Check for blanks and negative numbers and output message box

Tags: excel, vba

I have this and it works to make sure everything is a number. But i still want to do data validation to make sure it gives you and error if you try to leave blanks. And if it is not too much trouble how do I tweak my working code to make sure only positive numbers.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Const CELL_ADDRESS = "$C$5:$C$7,$C$9:$C$11,$C$12:$C$13,$C$15:$C$16,$C$18:$C$25"
If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range(CELL_ADDRESS)) Is Nothing Then
   If Not IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
      MsgBox "Please Enter Numerical Values Only", vbCritical, "Error"
      Target.Value = vbNullString
   End If
End If
End Sub


This is the blank code I have but It does not work.


'Validation for No Blank Cells
Private Sub Worksheet_Change1(ByVal Target As Range)
Const CELL_ADDRESS = "$C$5:$C$7,$C$9:$C$11,$C$12:$C$13,$C$15:$C$16,$C$18:$C$25"
If CELL_ADDRESS = "" Then
MsgBox "Please Enter Numerical Values", vbCritical, "Blank Cell(s)!"
'  End If
'    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range(CELL_ADDRESS)) Is Nothing Then
'       If IsEmpty(Range(CELL_ADDRESS)) Then
'         MsgBox "Please Enter Numerical Values for Cells C5:C7", vbCritical, "Blank Cell"
'     End If
'    End If End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just use data validation?

Comment: @findwindow: an advantage to using the Worksheet_Change event is that it will always fire, no matter what happens to the cells.  So if you copy/paste a cell over another cell which has data validation, the data validation is also copied away along with the old value (unless you protect the sheet).  The disadvantage of course is that while data validation moves along with their cells when inserting/deleting stuff, the macro doesn't adjust automagically.  But that can be remedied with VBA logic; do not store hardcoded cell adresses, but look them up dynamically (and error if they're not found).

Answer (score 0):

IsEmpty should work for this, but you need to pass it the cell's value, not the range representing the cell.  If you pass it the range, then it will always return False (since a valid range is an Object and thus not Empty).

So use this instead:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Const CELL_ADDRESS = "$C$5:$C$7,$C$9:$C$11,$C$12:$C$13,$C$15:$C$16,$C$18:$C$25"
  If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range(CELL_ADDRESS)) Is Nothing Then
    If IsEmpty(Target.Value) Then
      MsgBox "Please Enter Numerical Values for Cells C5:C7", vbCritical, "Blank Cell"
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

However, the given code only checks the .Value of the supplied Target.  If Target consists of more than once cell (which can happen if the user copy/pastes multiple cells over your checked range), then Target contains a range with multiple cells, and .Value will return an array with all those cell's values.  And an array <> Empty, so IsEmpty will fail there.

Best thing to do is to iterate over all cells in the intersection of your cells-to-check and Target, check each individual cell for IsEmpty, and then report the actual cells that are in violation (via the cells' .Address property).

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that I think produces the effect you are looking for. I created an event handler in the Worksheet that calls a subprocedure in another module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call Module1.TDang
End Sub
```

Then, in the Module1 code, I wrote the following:

```
Sub TDang()
'    This procedure assumes your column of numbers is static
     Dim MyCol As Range
     Dim Cell As Range

     Set MyCol = Worksheets("T Dang").Range("C5:C7, C9:C13, C15:C16, C18:C25")

     For Each Cell In MyCol
'         If all is good, clear colors
          If Cell.Value >= 0 And IsNumeric(Cell.Value) And Not IsEmpty(Cell.Value) Then
               Cell.Interior.Color = xlNone
          End If
'         Ensure values are positive numbers
          If Cell.Value < 0 Then
               MsgBox ("Values must not be negative." & vbNewLine & _
                       "Change " & Cell.Value & " in " & Cell.Address & " to a positive value.")
               Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
          End If
'         Ensure values are NOT letters
          If Not IsNumeric(Cell.Value) Then
               MsgBox ("Values can only be numeric." & vbNewLine & _
                       "Change '" & Cell.Value & "' in " & Cell.Address & " to a numeric value.")
               Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
          End If
'         Ensure there are no blanks
          If IsEmpty(Cell.Value) Then
               MsgBox ("Do not leave cell " & Cell.Address & " blank!")
               Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
          End If
     Next Cell
End Sub
```

If the Range of values in your column `C` change, you would simply need to change the MyCol Range variable. I tested it several times and it appears to work nicely. When the user is accessing this sheet, if she enters a letter, a negative, or a blank, then the event handler calls the macro and it gives the user a friendly message and then highlights the offending cell in red. If all the values are good, then it appears as if no event occurs!